# Using fetch with Express, React, cors, cookies - 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, fetch, csrf

spent a lot of time trying to figure this out with no success. I'm trying to get csurf protection running with cookies. At the moment I've simplified the following code as much as I can. I'm running a fetch request from React to another server on Express. It gives the error:

*"Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3003/testlogin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."*

As I understand, the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is set in my corsOptions. So it shouldn't throw this error. I'm clearly missing something. Any help gratefully received.

Express server:

```
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require("express");
const csrf = require("csurf");

const app = express();

const csrfMiddleware = csrf({ cookie: true });

app.use(cookieParser());

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',   
  methods: "GET,HEAD,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS",
  credentials: true,               
  allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Accept",
}
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions))

app.use(csrfMiddleware);

app.post("/testlogin", cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  console.log('test login reached', );
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: "success" }));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3003;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Front-end (react):

```
function testClick() {
  console.log("testClick Clicked");

  let urlToGetUserProfile = 'http://localhost:3003/testlogin'

  return fetch(urlToGetUserProfile, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify({ idToken: "idTokengoeshere" }),
  })
    .then((fetchResponse) => {
      console.log(fetchResponse);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csrfMiddleware` middleware function gets called before the `cors` middleware.

It throws `ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token` which stops the `cors` middleware from adding headers to the response.

You can resolve that by putting the `cors` middleware **first**.

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(csrfMiddleware);

app.post("/testlogin",(req, res) => {
  console.log('test login reached', );
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: "success" }));
});
```

Comment: Ah fantastic. That seems to have stopped the CORS issue. I'm now getting an error in my server:
"ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token"

You wouldn't know the problem would you?

Comment: Presumably, you don't have the cookie with the CSRF token in it stored in the browser against `http://localhost:3003/`. You also don't have the token in any header or the body.

Comment: In my request headers I get:
Cookie: _csrf=wgyr7qT7wY-nLAVGTLgz80Kx

So it looks like it's being sent? 

In my developer tools the _csrf cookie is also showing. The domain is 'localhost' and the path is '/'.

Comment: OK, so it is the lack of matching token in the body or headers of the request.